# search the history for the all tables that are created by a user

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm new in oracle/sql world., and i know how to find a answer by myself searching., and searching again .. but for my new issue i d'ont find a good answer, so i just want to find the history of manipulation the database by filtering the user who created the last tables, what tables are, when he created it etc .. is sql oracle

I'm using oracle XE and the client is toad.

i try it with

```
select table_name from sys.dba_tables where owner='system'
```

but is not display the tables that i was created with the system user a few months ago., and now i forget what tables i was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String matching is case-sensitive, and most things in the data dictionary are stored in all upper-case as a general rule.  So your example query should return some rows if you change the literal to upper case:

```
select table_name from sys.dba_tables where owner='SYSTEM'
```

If you want to see recently-created tables, you'll need to join this with `dba_objects` and use the `created` column there to filter or sort.

Of course, if you really just want to see tables for the schema you are currently logged into, `user_tables` is a better view to query.

Per your comment, here's how to get the last-modified time for each table:

```
select table_name, last_ddl_time
  from dba_tables t
       join dba_objects o
         on o.object_name=t.table_name and o.object_type='TABLE' and o.owner = t.owner
  where t.owner='SYSTEM'
    and last_ddl_time >= date '2011-01-02'
    and last_ddl_time <  date '2011-01-10'
```

(Note that "modified" means a change to the table definition, not to the data it contains.)

Comment: great the first query., i put the system in upper-case 'SYSTEM' and now i see the all tables created by the past year .. but still pending how to search in these tables for a explicit date .. let say 01/02/2011

Comment: i mean i want to know the tables that was created or the tables that have modificacions from 01/02/2011 to 01/09/2011 by 'SYSTEM' user

Comment: Good answer. note that if you want just the table create date as your filter, then look at the "CREATED" field rather than the last_ddl_time field for your where clause.

Comment: Dave my friend your answer is definitely great., god bless you!!

Comment: ohh.. is not working, but i'm very sure that your query is correct, just is something that have wrong, plase Dave i attach a screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/errored.png/ i use toad like a client and oracle xe like database., thank you so much

Comment: Sorry, needed to qualify `owner` with a table alias.  For that matter, I realized that owner should be in the join conditions as well.  I've now actually tested it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
select * from tab;
```

or

```
select * from user_tables;
```

Both will give the list of tables created by user (you).

Comment: is not good your answer, because is disply a lot of tables generic by oracle xe in the column table_name and in another column table_type if is view, sequence, table .. so i want to see the tables that was created it by user system a few month ago, and if we can select and the date that the tables was created it, that's great